# BeautifulSoup: Printing out also the start-tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

actually, I'm using BeautifulSoup. This code print out the content of the class main:

```
for text in soup.find_all("table", {'class', 'main'}):
        txt += text
```

This is already a good thing, but how is it possible to also include the "start tag", which is here `<class="main" ...>` ?

Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: No, the start tag would be `<table class="main">`. And `find_all()` doesn't return text, it returns `bs4.Tag()` objects. You are just not matching what you think you are matching. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a *set* instead of a *dictionary*. Do:

```
for text in soup.find_all("table", {'class':'main'}):
#                                          ^ colon here instead of a comma
        txt += text
```

Comment: But this doesn't change anything... The first tag (something like "<table class="main" frame="box" etc>") is not represented :(

Answer (score 0):

```
for el in soup.findAll('table', {'class':'main'}):
    print el.text         # text is here
    print el.attrs        # all attributes is here
```